# FluentNHibernate download does not contain log4net

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, log4net

I'm trying to migrate from NHibernate 2.1 to NHibernate 3.1. The FluentNHibernate 1.2 download contains lots of NHibernate dlls, as if it is trying to bundle everything required for NHibernate. But it doesn't seem to contain log4net. Does anyone know why? Is there something I'm missing here? Is log4net not strictly necessary?

Edit: it also doesn't contain the bytecode providers for LinFu or Spring, only Castle. Is there a reason for that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate 3.1 does not require log4net. If uses it if available.

Also, it includes its own bytecode provider, so the external ones are not needed anymore either.

Comment: So if I'm using Castle anyway for DI, should I use that, or just use the default? What's the consensus?

Comment: @David: unless you need to do something with the proxies, just leave the default.

Comment: Ace, thanks. Pointless additional bit to get me over minimum character limit.